# Downloading file from HTTPS works from browser but not from C#

Tags: c#, https, certificate, webclient

I have a problem with downloading file from **HTTPS**. Server is 3rd party and it's providing TXT transaction data to download (something like https://blabla.dat). Validation using IP address (from invalid IP you get 403 error).
From browser (IE, Mozilla) download works perfectly but from C# a get timeout...

I tried to set

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

and then download the file...

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(url, dest);
```

and it works for some HTTPS (like images from HTTPS Facebook) but not in my case. (weird)

I also tried to set Credentials and Header (no change).

```
        webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        webClient.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        webClient.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;       
        webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

How can I download this file? Something like simulating IE request and accept certificate??? I'm new to this kind of issues. Thank you very much!

**EDIT 20130903 1606**

It works perfectly on localhost using VPN (to gain server's IP) but does nothing on Windows Server 2008 R2. It is not responding for some time and then thow WebException (timeout)...

Comment: May be your browser works through proxy ?

Comment: I'm deleloping my app on Win8 and trying to run on WinServer 2008 R2. I set VPN on server (to get server's IP) and HTTPS download works! But the app throws WebException when I copy .exe to server and run it.

Comment: Is WinServer 2008 connect to the 3rd party Server directly ? If yes, you must to remove in release version of exe any proxy and gateways.

Comment: WinServer is connected directly and has its own IPv4. There is no proxy or gateway settings in app. When I use only webclient.downloadfile() without special options, it works on localohost but not on WinServer... :( It does nothing and after some time it thows exception.

Comment: I found this article but it looks weird to me: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980817

Comment: It seems it's not a app trouble. It's a server configuration trouble, I suppose. See a brandmauer at server, the rules for connections on 443 port. Try to run app As Administrator.

Comment: TCP port 443 is enabled. I have tried to run app As Administrator but still with the same result... nothing nothing nothing and then timeout. BUT when I try to download another file from HTTP (not HTTPS) (on win server) from another server, it works. I suppose it is not firewall problem cause I can download it from localhost using server's VPN (???)